# Selecting all but children

Tags: html, jquery-selectors

I've got a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="foo">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="link.bar">Good</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li>
                    <a href="otherlink.baz">Bad</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to select the "good" `a` without selecting the "bad" `a` (using jQuery). I've tried `.foo ul:not(.children) li a` but that doesn't work (obviously). Would it be possible to achieve in a one-liner?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XRgwX/)

Comment: You could look for direct descendant `.foo > ul > li > a`

Comment: @Niklas I think that your comment is better than current answers. So maybe it should be an answer

Comment: @Oriol added it as an answer as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look for direct descendant `.foo > ul > li > a`

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it's one of the ways...

`var good= $("a[href='link.bar']")`...

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: The links are dynamic, so this wouldn't be a solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

in this particular scenario that you gave . it can be done by one lineras follows

```
$(a ,'.foo').first();
```

I hope it helps. If it does not work, do let me know and I'll delete my answer. thanks.